# asp.net how to add TemplateField programmatically for about 10 dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, detailsview, edititemtemplate

This is my third time asking this question. I am not getting good answers regarding this. I wish I could get some help but I will keep asking this question because its a good question and SO experts should not ignore this...

So I have about 10 dropdownlist controls that I add manually in the DetailsView control manually like follows. I should be able to add this programmatically. Please help and do not ignore...

```
  <asp:DetailsView ID="dvProfile" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="memberid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        OnPreRender = "_onprerender"

        Height="50px" onm="" Width="125px">

        <Fields>


           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Your Gender">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" 
                                            DataSourceid="ddlDAGender"
                                            DataTextField="Gender" DataValueField="GenderID"
                                            SelectedValue='<%#Bind("GenderID") %>'
                                >

                             </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate >
                                <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>' ID="lblGender"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

=======================================================

Added on 5/3/09

This is what I have so far and I still can not add the drop down list programmatically.

```
private void PopulateItemTemplate(string luControl)
{
    SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource();
    ds = (SqlDataSource)FindControl("ddlDAGender");
    DataView dvw = new DataView();
    DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();

    dvw = (DataView)ds.Select(args);
    DataTable dt = dvw.ToTable();


    DetailsView dv = (DetailsView)LoginView2.FindControl("dvProfile");

    TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
    tf.HeaderText = "Your Gender";
    tf.ItemTemplate = new ProfileItemTemplate("Gender", ListItemType.Item);
    tf.EditItemTemplate = new ProfileItemTemplate("Gender", ListItemType.EditItem);
    dv.Fields.Add(tf);
}


public class ProfileItemTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private string ctlName;
    ListItemType _lit;
    private string _strDDLName;
    private string _strDVField;
    private string _strDTField;
    private string _strSelectedID;
    private DataTable _dt;


    public ProfileItemTemplate(string strDDLName, 
                                                        string strDVField, 
                                                        string strDTField,
                                                        DataTable dt
                                                        )
    {
        _dt = dt;
        _strDDLName = strDDLName;
        _strDVField = strDVField;
        _strDTField = strDTField;
    }

    public ProfileItemTemplate(string strDDLName,
                                                    string strDVField,
                                                    string strDTField,
                                                    string strSelectedID,
                                                    DataTable dt
                                                    )
    {
        _dt = dt;
        _strDDLName = strDDLName;
        _strDVField = strDVField;
        _strDTField = strDTField;
        _strSelectedID = strSelectedID;
    }

    public ProfileItemTemplate(string ControlName, ListItemType lit)
    {
        ctlName = ControlName;
        _lit = lit;


    }



    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {


        switch(_lit)
        {
            case ListItemType.Item : 
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.ddl_DataBinding_item);
                container.Controls.Add(lbl);
                break;
            case ListItemType.EditItem :
                DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.lbl_DataBinding);
                container.Controls.Add(ddl);

                break;
        }
    }

    private void ddl_DataBinding_item(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        ddl.ID = _strDDLName;
        ddl.DataSource = _dt;
        ddl.DataValueField = _strDVField;
        ddl.DataTextField = _strDVField;
    }



    private void lbl_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)sender;
        lbl.ID = "lblGender";

        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        ddl.ID = _strDDLName;
        ddl.DataSource = _dt;
        ddl.DataValueField = _strDVField;
        ddl.DataTextField = _strDTField;
        for (int i = 0; i < _dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_strSelectedID == _dt.Rows[i][_strDVField].ToString())
            {
                ddl.SelectedIndex = i;
            }
        }

        lbl.Text = ddl.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop making answers which contain valuable question information... just edit your question.

Comment: got it... my bad... I will do that next time...

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? What problem are you having? If you haven't answered these questions before, then it's no surprise that you haven't received a good answer.

Obviously, you have to locate the TemplateFields for which you want to add dropdowns, and you have to set their EditItemTemplate property to an instance of a class that implements ITemplate. That instance will have it's `InstantiateIn` method called to add controls to a parent control. In this case, this is where you would configure and add your DropDownList.

If this description is not adequate, then you'll have to say in what way it's not adequate, so that I or someone else can answer.

Comment: The DetailsView has a Fields property, which has an indexer, so view.Fields[0].